# Domain keeps Windows 8.1 computer from sleeping

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, domain

I've recently went back from Win 10 Tech preview to Windows 8.1, where my computer has been connected to my home domain with both operative systemes.

This has never been an issue before and I havent changed any hardware, but when the computer is connected to my domain, it never sleeps. I've set the timer to 1 minute but the computer just goes to the login screen and sits there forever. Not even turning off the screen.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
HID Keyboard Device
HID-kompatibel mus (001)
HID Keyboard Device (002)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.
```

I've tried disabling my network adaptors, enable the power saving feature on USB ports and the domain controller itself doesn't push out any special energy settins through policies.

Immediately when I disconnect from my domain, the sleep/hibernate schedule works as intended.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean when you say "disconnect from the domain"? Do you pull the network cable or leave the domain by joining a workgroup?

Comment: When I leave the domain and go back to a temporary workgroup.

Comment: Try here: http://superuser.com/questions/532993/why-wont-my-computer-go-to-sleep-automatically