# PC will not automatically turn off screen or go to sleep. "powercfg /requests" shows nothing

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

I realize this probably has been asked before but I've tried everything in this thread and still nothing has worked: [Why won't my computer go to sleep automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/532993/why-wont-my-computer-go-to-sleep-automatically)

Summary: PC is no longer going to sleep automatically or even turning off the monitor. I can manually put it to sleep and awake it with no issues. I currently have it set to sleep after 1 minute for testing.

Running Win 10 Enterprise x64

Things I've tried:

- Removed all peripherals, mouse, keyboard
- Closed all applications
- Windows fully updated
- Disabled wake timers
- Checked power plan and disabled all "keep pc awake" settings; disabled hybrid sleep, enabled allow computer to sleep with media
- Checked device manager and made sure nothing can wake PC.
- Checked Task Scheduler for running tasks and ended them
- I use Plex Media Server, but I've tested shutting down the service.

cmd powercfg /requests or /waketimers shows nothing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ356.jpg

Only recent changes to my PC have been adding a Gigabyte RTX 3070 GPU and I added a new monitor so now I have two.

I feel like I've tried everything I could find on google so now I'm trying here. Thanks in advance to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after posting this. I saw a post in the sidebar that caught my attention:
[Windows 10 Desktop PC will not go to sleep automatically based on set idle timer no matter what I try. What else can I try?](https://superuser.com/questions/1633518/windows-10-desktop-pc-will-not-go-to-sleep-automatically-based-on-set-idle-timer?rq=1)
An answer from user Aenfa, who posted an AutoHotkey script that helped isolate the issue:

```
loop
{
  Sleep, 500
  Tooltip, %A_TimeIdle%
}

ESC::
ExitApp
```

I ran the script and started unplugging things and found that the issue was with my PS4 controller connected via usb. I was sure I had unplugged it to test, so either I didn't wait long enough, or some other things I tried helped as well.